# Unable to start android emulator from an external storage device(External SSD)!

Tags: android, android-emulator

I installed the android sdk on an external SSD. When I tried to start the SDKManager.exe, I see a command line window open for a second and close. But the sdk manager wouldn't start. Am I missing anything? Can we run android from an external storage device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the path to android sdk in my jdeveloper was wrong